# If control m is calling a database job what nls_date_format the session use

Tags: database, control-m

If control m is calling a database job what nls_date_format the session use.

I am getting not a valid month error and when I am rerunning it, it is completing successfully.
For most of the control m jobs it is happening

I am thinking the nls_data_format will get overridden by client i. e. Control m.